# Sending Variables in Post without the input tag

Tags: php, html, post

I want to send only one variable via the post method. I have queried the database and have to post $row[id] variable to the page along with the form. To send the user's input we simply write like `<input type="text" name="xyz"></input>` and then we access it as $_POST[xyz]. This way we can send a variable that a user write. But, I want to send something that user has not written but there in my sending file as $row['id']. So, I want to send this variable as well. How can I do that? And also how will I be able to access that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `<input type="hidden">`

Answer (score 2):

define that variable after post. :)

set `$row['id'] = 'valueXYZ';` at post script. more effective to prevent cheating `$_POST` value